# Fastest way to select and reassign elements in an array based on complex conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

What is the fastest way to select and reassign elements based on complex conditions in numpy, such as:

```
# some 1-d array of floats
myarray = np.array(myarray)
# set any foo's or bar's from myarray to 0
myarray[where(map(lambda x: foo(x) or bar(x), myarray))] = 0
```

is the solution to use `np.vectorize`? or `np.select` perhaps?

Comment: Can you vectorize foo and bar?

Comment: As @CookieOfFortune points out, your best bet is someting along the lines of: `myarray[vec_foo(myarray) | vec_bar(myarray)] = 0`.

Comment: what sort of conditions are you trying filter on, can you provide an example?

Comment: @did you check the answers below?

Answer (score 1):

The fastest may be using fancy indexing with an array containing all the conditions:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(1000)
cond1 = x % 2 == 0      # getting the even numbers
cond2 = x**0.5 % 1 == 0 # getting those with exact square root
cond3 = x % 3 == 0      # getting those divisible by 3
cond =np.all(np.array((cond1,cond2,cond3)),axis=0)
print x[ cond ]
#[  0  36 144 324 576 900]
```

Using `np.all` means cond1 and cond2 and cond3.

Using `np.any` means cond1 or  cond2  or cond3.

This would faster if all conditions were created in a predifined array of booleans:

```
conds = np.zeros((3,1000),dtype='bool')
```

And then assign each condition to one line in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Can also use np.where():

```
In [7]: a[np.where((a % 2 == 0) & (a % 3 == 0) & (a ** 0.5 % 1 == 0))]
Out[7]: array([  0,  36, 144, 324, 576, 900])
```